# Как при помощи Stream API отфильтровать такие списки?

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть 2 списка, к примеру 1-й `[1,2,3,4,5]` и 2-й `[2,4,5]`. Как при помощи Stream API сравнить их таким образом, что-бы в первом остались только те, которых нету во втором, `[1,3]`.

Comment: Почему такая привязка к Stream API?

Comment: Хочу научиться минимизировать количество кода в методах, не требующих скорости отработки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение "в лоб":

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 5);
List<Integer> list3 = list1.stream().filter(i -> !list2.contains(i)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Но это не очень здорово, т.к. время выполения будет *O(n * m)*.

Поэтому стоит обернуть второй список в `HashSet` и получить что-то похожее на  *O(n)*

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Set<Integer> list2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(2, 4, 5));
List<Integer> list3 = list1.stream().filter(i -> !list2.contains(i)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

---

Правда все это не выглядит лаконичным по сравнению с обычной гуавой, которая валяется в `CLASSPATH` почти любого проекта:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

Set<Integer> set1 = Sets.newHashSet(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Set<Integer> set2 = Sets.newHashSet(2, 4, 5);
Set<Integer> set3 = Sets.difference(set1, set2);
```

Comment: Рекомендация: используйте переносы для длинных строк кода

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать

Answer (score 7):

Лично я не вижу смысла здесь использовать Stream API, когда есть готовый метод `Collection.removeAll`:

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 5);
list1.removeAll(list2); // Будет лежать [1, 3]
```

Comment: Спасибо, я думал, что removeAll по другому работает